# Setup logentries for aws ecs

Tags: aws-ecs, logentries

I'am trying to make my aws elastic cluster service send logs to logentries.
But I can't find any good documentation on how to do it.

When i create task definition I have the option to choose logentries as image below shows: 
[image]

But where do I find this token? 
And do I have to do anything else?

All i can find on the topic is this:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent them an email an got a answer:

> hi,
>
> A token can be generated by logging in > Clicking Add Data > Quick Add
>
> > Fill out log name details > create new token > you will be presented with a token. This can be pasted into the setup.
>
> Depending on your setup if you also follow the add data flow you will
>   see a docker option. I would also look at the following:
>
> https://insightops.help.rapid7.com/docs/docker-1

btw, i think they are called rapid7 insightops now :)